# If cells match, then index them

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of licensed FL dealers. The list has 3 core data types:

1) The dealer entity name
2) The dealership location
3) The mailing address of the dealer entity

I want to find dealers that own 3 or more stores. I would like to sort by mailing address of the dealer entity, if 3 or more rows approximately match from the mailing address column, I would like to index those rows on another sheet.

I am using mailing address of the dealer entity instead of dealer entity name as dealers often use different entities for each store, but will have all of their entity related mail go to the same place. I also say "approximately" match for the rows as there is a fair amount of manual entry, and there are always errors.

Is this possible? What is the function? I am attaching a link to the data itself.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AkNOEF7pE-Yksi9lcGGwq2tM3QYqsHr5lFrN74rk_h0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code**.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:P, 
 "select G,count(G) 
  where G is not null 
  group by G", 1), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2>2
  order by Col1", 1)
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sH-8I8IOhNQRW-6toR1F9vnANUTHStUtLetndEuXo6k/edit#gid=1126749162)**

Answer (score -1):

I have added a format fix,hoping to remove any character case issue and trailing spaces and have collated the required data in another sheet.
P.S. manual entry may be leading to inaccuracy.

I have [Attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s9JgIG4Qd45_LKdixy6aU1n56YFm1BcgpwQsD9AypHU/edit#gid=886393356) the sheet here.

Comment: wondering why you got only 40 results compared to mine 85... >> **Sheet1!$A$1:$Q$7198**

Comment: Put a filter on Sheet 1 and narrow data using "13606 COUNTY LINE RD", you'll get three rows of data with                                                                                                   
DEALER NAME : IPS  AUTO PART INC and 
LOCATION ADDRESS : 13606 COUNTY LINE RD.    The query you are using will count this a dealership with three different location.   We need to first narrow a unique set like how I have done in format fixes tab.    Also added Required data-2 which might provide better understanding

Comment: @player0 & Shrvan D, you are legends. I cannot thank you enough for the help with this.

Comment: Xavier happy to help.. let me know if you need any data related stuff done in Google spreadsheet 